# Javascript inefficient arrays issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, user-input

I'm currently working on a small project in Javascript that asks the user 5 questions. They have 15 guesses to get all questions right.

```
var questions = [question1, question2, question3, question4, question5];
var answers = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4", "answer5"];
```

If they get the question right, it displays the next question. If their answer is too high, it displays "too high", and same goes for when their answer is too low.

Here, the code sets a text area to question[0] to ask the first question. The variable correctGuess is set to answer[0], the first answer.

```
setText("questionText", questions[0]);
var guess = getText("answer");
correctGuess == answers[0]
```

Now this is where it gets messy. I put in a for loop because my friend suggested it. Ideally, whenever the guess is correct, the i would increase by 1 so that the next question is displayed. Ideally, this would apply to the answers as well.

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
if (guess == correctGuess) {
  setText("questionText",questions[i])
} else {
  guessBig();
  guessSmall();
}
}
```

Here are the functions that are called if the guess is not correct. It removes one guess from the user, and displays "too big" or "too small" depending on the value of both the guess and the correctGuess.

```
function guessBig() {
  if (guess > correctGuess) {
    setText("result", "Too big!");
    guessesLeft--;
  }
}

function guessSmall() {
  if (guess > correctGuess) {
    setText("result", "Too small!");
    guessesLeft--;
  }
}
```

I don't know why it's not working. I'm not an experienced coder and came to StackOverflow so that I could learn from the collective knowledge and experience of coders from around the world.

If you don't mind, I would really appreciate it if you could take a minute to help me out with my mini-project. Thank you!

Comment: How is the user input provided? Something blocking or non-blocking? If non-blocking (which is preferable) then a `for` loop is not the right tool.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think it's non-blocking. What tool should I use instead? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you examine it more closely and try to be *certain* of whether it's blocking or non-blocking? Should be pretty obvious, and it has a big impact on how the script needs to be structured

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, but I'm new to programming, so I'm not sure what blocking or non-blocking is.

Answer (score 2):

I'll buy into your answer in the comments above that the input (and output) aren't important to your question. There's a couple places to optimize. In real life, you'd want to consider how many items will be in the array and how it impacts your user experience, because that may change the way you structure your code. You said you're new to programming though, so let's see what we can do.

You have more functions assigned to memory and function calls than you need. So, I'd remove repeated code.

```
function wrongGuess() {
  guessesLeft--;
  if (guess > correctGuess) {
    setText("result", "Too big!");
  } else if (guess > correctGuess) {
    setText("result", "Too small!");
  }
}
```

You could also  just make that else, since you know it's not going to be equal.

```
function wrongGuess(tooBig) {
  guessesLeft--;
  if (tooBig) {
    setText("result", "Too big!");
  } else {
    setText("result", "Too small!");
  }
}
```

Then you'd call it with the inequality expression in the invokation.

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  if (guess == correctGuess) {
    setText("questionText",questions[i])
  } else {
    wrongGuess(guess > correctGuess)
  }
}
```

I still have some problems with this. I like my functions to do one thing, set something or return something. So I'd move the changing of the guesses left out. This way, we know the function is only going to set the output.

```
function wrongGuess(tooBig) {
  if (tooBig) {
    setText("result", "Too big!");
  } else {
    setText("result", "Too small!");
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  if (guess == correctGuess) {
    setText("questionText",questions[i])
  } else {
    guessesLeft--;
    wrongGuess(guess > correctGuess)
  }
}
```

Now, we can get rid of some extra memory overhead and reduce code footprint.

```
function highOrLow(tooBig) {
  return tooBig ? "Too big!": "Too small!";
  // this is the short hand for this
  // var message;
  // if (tooBig === true) {
  //    message = "TooBig!";
  // } else {
  //    message = "TooSmall!";
  // }
  // return message;
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  if (guess == correctGuess) {
    setText("questionText", questions[i])
  } else {
    guessesLeft--;
    setText("result", highOrLow(guess > correctGuess));
  }
}
```

Now, onto the loop. You could do forEach. Additionally, you could also get your answers here. Depending on if you need to or not. That way you're not storing it in another place.

```
function highOrLow(tooBig) {
  return tooBig ? "Too big!": "Too small!";
}

questions.forEach((question, index) =>
  {      
    if (guess == answers[index]) {
      setText("questionText", question);
    } else {
      guessesLeft--;
      setText("result", highOrLow(guess > correctGuess));
    }
  });
  // added semicolons for my mental health.
```

This version is not higher performance than a for loop on it's own. But it's easier to read and can prevent memory leaks and repeated code, which is better for performance overall. This of course relies on other things looking right, and some of it is fishy.

Comment: Thank you! I'm coding in Code.org studios though for my AP Computer Science class, and unfortunately,                                                
function highOrLow(tooBig) {
  return tooBig "Too big!": "Too small!"; 
}  does not work on Code.org. Could you please help me out with that? Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: your comment is missing the questions mark, do you have it on code.org?  return tooBig ? "Too big!": "Too small!";

Comment: Either way, I added a comment to explain the "ternary operator" and the long hand version.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to include the question mark in the comment.